# Highcharts polar display custom label name or icons

Tags: javascript, highcharts, icons, customization

I need to display, for each quarter the label name of the serie's element `data.name`.

And in order to improve the user reliability I need to replace these labels by custom icons.

Here is my current Polar chart :

http://jsfiddle.net/eento/xnkabtfu/

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single series and set `legendType: 'point'` in the series - less series gives better performance.

One way to solve your problem could be to to use Font Awesome icons. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/p48kpy0j/

To enable Font Awesome icons in exported image see a Highcharts plugin - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/2A7Zf/) ([source](https://twitter.com/highcharts/status/471614909806292992)).

Another way might be to add images in `dataLabels.formatter` throught HTML's `<img>`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/p48kpy0j/1/